# How do I use a single shell instance to run multiple commands in Python? (To avoid shell startup time)

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, zeromq, rpc

I want to create a `bash` (or `zsh`, it doesn't matter.) server, that accepts commands, runs them and returns the results (`return code`, `stdout`, `stderr`). My purpose is to avoid starting a new `bash` instance for every `bash` command I want to run in my `Python` script, since my `bash` dotfiles take fairly long to load. Something in the spirit of:

```
bash = bash_instance() # pay the startup penalty ONCE
bash.run('echo hi') # Just run the command without the startup time
...
bash.run('curl ipinfo.io')
return_code, stdout, stderr = bash.run('cat file.txt')
```

A kind of `Remote Method Call` for the shell.

Comment: maybe dont use the shell at all, but code directly in python and let python call other python functions??

Comment: @NikosM. I find zsh a better language for most of my scripting needs. Python is needlessly general-purpose for my usecases. But I do need a competent bridge between languages. Anyways, I don't like rewriting all of my scripts.

Comment: do you mean use `partial` on subprocess perhaps?

Comment: @gold_cy Is the question more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

zsh = zsh_instance()

with Pool(5) as p:
    print(p.map(zsh.run, [
        ('some-command',),
        ('some-other-command',)
    ]))
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear. There is no `zsh_instance`; I am asking how I can implement something like that. `zsh` is a shell, like `bash`. I want to create a way to feed it commands without starting a new shell every time.